# Scan Ble Android / getName() or device not complete or null

Tags: android, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'have an issue with the BLE scan of Android, I dont get the full name of the scanned devices found, I get only the first letter do you have any idea how to resolve this issue ?

I'm working with a 7.0 Nougat device which is supporting BLE

This is a part of my code :

```
   mBluetoothScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
                .build();

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                    messageLog.error("onScanResult");
                    BluetoothDevice btDevice = null;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                        btDevice = result.getDevice();
                        messageLog.error("btDevice : " + btDevice.getName() + "|" + btDevice.getAddress() + "|" + Arrays.toString(btDevice.getUuids()));
                    }
                    if (btDevice != null && btDevice.getName() != null && !isInDeviceList(btDevice))
                        mDeviceList.add(btDevice);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                    Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
                }
            };
        }
```

With btDevice.getName( ) I only get the first letter of a device scanned, is this my fault or is it coming from the Android BLE API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the peripheral's name does not fit in the Advertising data since it needs to include other data therein, it will only send the prefix of the name over the air. It's nothing you can do about that other than change the advertisement data in the peripheral's firmware.

To get the exact advertisement data, you can investigate the "result.getScanRecord()" ScanRecord in onScanResult.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to change the name in the firmware and I will tell you if it's working. I have tried the "result.getScanRecord()" and I have manage to get the 8 first letters, Do you think that it's a fixed number of bytes ?

Comment: Thanks sir :) I have used result.getScanRecord() instead of getName and change the name in the firmware, have a nice day !